# collapse для html

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть html-страница, сохраненная из браузера. На ней используется collapse(аккордеон). Помимо этого аккордеона js содержит другие ненужные библиотеки (flexslider, popover и т.д.). Уже битый час пытаюсь в этом js оставить только аккордеон, но ничего не получается - убираю лишний код, но постоянно вылазят ошибки. Может кто-то сможет помочь оставить в коде только collapse?

```
t("./vendor/bootstrap/collapse.js"),
```

[Ссылка на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Aleks/uj62qt8k/1/)

Comment: Лучше новый сделай.

Answer (score 0):

На странице https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/customize/ оставить галки только у collapse и нажать кнопку внизу страницы.
В скачанном архиве будет `bootstrap.min.js` и `bootstrap.js`. Их и можно использовать.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
/*!
 * Generated using the Bootstrap Customizer (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/customize/)
 */

/*!
 * Bootstrap v3.4.0 (https://getbootstrap.com/)
 * Copyright 2011-2018 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under the MIT license
 */

if (typeof jQuery === 'undefined') {
  throw new Error('Bootstrap\'s JavaScript requires jQuery')
}
+function ($) {
  'use strict';
  var version = $.fn.jquery.split(' ')[0].split('.')
  if ((version[0] < 2 && version[1] < 9) || (version[0] == 1 && version[1] == 9 && version[2] < 1) || (version[0] > 3)) {
    throw new Error('Bootstrap\'s JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 4')
  }
}(jQuery);

/* ========================================================================
 * Bootstrap: collapse.js v3.4.0
 * https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#collapse
 * ========================================================================
 * Copyright 2011-2018 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 * ======================================================================== */

/* jshint latedef: false */

+function ($) {
  'use strict';

  // COLLAPSE PUBLIC CLASS DEFINITION
  // ================================

  var Collapse = function (element, options) {
    this.$element      = $(element)
    this.options       = $.extend({}, Collapse.DEFAULTS, options)
    this.$trigger      = $('[data-toggle="collapse"][href="#' + element.id + '"],' +
                           '[data-toggle="collapse"][data-target="#' + element.id + '"]')
    this.transitioning = null

    if (this.options.parent) {
      this.$parent = this.getParent()
    } else {
      this.addAriaAndCollapsedClass(this.$element, this.$trigger)
    }

    if (this.options.toggle) this.toggle()
  }

  Collapse.VERSION  = '3.4.0'

  Collapse.TRANSITION_DURATION = 350

  Collapse.DEFAULTS = {
    toggle: true
  }

  Collapse.prototype.dimension = function () {
    var hasWidth = this.$element.hasClass('width')
    return hasWidth ? 'width' : 'height'
  }

  Collapse.prototype.show = function () {
    if (this.transitioning || this.$element.hasClass('in')) return

    var activesData
    var actives = this.$parent && this.$parent.children('.panel').children('.in, .collapsing')

    if (actives && actives.length) {
      activesData = actives.data('bs.collapse')
      if (activesData && activesData.transitioning) return
    }

    var startEvent = $.Event('show.bs.collapse')
    this.$element.trigger(startEvent)
    if (startEvent.isDefaultPrevented()) return

    if (actives && actives.length) {
      Plugin.call(actives, 'hide')
      activesData || actives.data('bs.collapse', null)
    }

    var dimension = this.dimension()

    this.$element
      .removeClass('collapse')
      .addClass('collapsing')[dimension](0)
      .attr('aria-expanded', true)

    this.$trigger
      .removeClass('collapsed')
      .attr('aria-expanded', true)

    this.transitioning = 1

    var complete = function () {
      this.$element
        .removeClass('collapsing')
        .addClass('collapse in')[dimension]('')
      this.transitioning = 0
      this.$element
        .trigger('shown.bs.collapse')
    }

    if (!$.support.transition) return complete.call(this)

    var scrollSize = $.camelCase(['scroll', dimension].join('-'))

    this.$element
      .one('bsTransitionEnd', $.proxy(complete, this))
      .emulateTransitionEnd(Collapse.TRANSITION_DURATION)[dimension](this.$element[0][scrollSize])
  }

  Collapse.prototype.hide = function () {
    if (this.transitioning || !this.$element.hasClass('in')) return

    var startEvent = $.Event('hide.bs.collapse')
    this.$element.trigger(startEvent)
    if (startEvent.isDefaultPrevented()) return

    var dimension = this.dimension()

    this.$element[dimension](this.$element[dimension]())[0].offsetHeight

    this.$element
      .addClass('collapsing')
      .removeClass('collapse in')
      .attr('aria-expanded', false)

    this.$trigger
      .addClass('collapsed')
      .attr('aria-expanded', false)

    this.transitioning = 1

    var complete = function () {
      this.transitioning = 0
      this.$element
        .removeClass('collapsing')
        .addClass('collapse')
        .trigger('hidden.bs.collapse')
    }

    if (!$.support.transition) return complete.call(this)

    this.$element
      [dimension](0)
      .one('bsTransitionEnd', $.proxy(complete, this))
      .emulateTransitionEnd(Collapse.TRANSITION_DURATION)
  }

  Collapse.prototype.toggle = function () {
    this[this.$element.hasClass('in') ? 'hide' : 'show']()
  }

  Collapse.prototype.getParent = function () {
    return $(document).find(this.options.parent)
      .find('[data-toggle="collapse"][data-parent="' + this.options.parent + '"]')
      .each($.proxy(function (i, element) {
        var $element = $(element)
        this.addAriaAndCollapsedClass(getTargetFromTrigger($element), $element)
      }, this))
      .end()
  }

  Collapse.prototype.addAriaAndCollapsedClass = function ($element, $trigger) {
    var isOpen = $element.hasClass('in')

    $element.attr('aria-expanded', isOpen)
    $trigger
      .toggleClass('collapsed', !isOpen)
      .attr('aria-expanded', isOpen)
  }

  function getTargetFromTrigger($trigger) {
    var href
    var target = $trigger.attr('data-target')
      || (href = $trigger.attr('href')) && href.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]+$)/, '') // strip for ie7

    return $(document).find(target)
  }


  // COLLAPSE PLUGIN DEFINITION
  // ==========================

  function Plugin(option) {
    return this.each(function () {
      var $this   = $(this)
      var data    = $this.data('bs.collapse')
      var options = $.extend({}, Collapse.DEFAULTS, $this.data(), typeof option == 'object' && option)

      if (!data && options.toggle && /show|hide/.test(option)) options.toggle = false
      if (!data) $this.data('bs.collapse', (data = new Collapse(this, options)))
      if (typeof option == 'string') data[option]()
    })
  }

  var old = $.fn.collapse

  $.fn.collapse             = Plugin
  $.fn.collapse.Constructor = Collapse


  // COLLAPSE NO CONFLICT
  // ====================

  $.fn.collapse.noConflict = function () {
    $.fn.collapse = old
    return this
  }


  // COLLAPSE DATA-API
  // =================

  $(document).on('click.bs.collapse.data-api', '[data-toggle="collapse"]', function (e) {
    var $this   = $(this)

    if (!$this.attr('data-target')) e.preventDefault()

    var $target = getTargetFromTrigger($this)
    var data    = $target.data('bs.collapse')
    var option  = data ? 'toggle' : $this.data()

    Plugin.call($target, option)
  })

}(jQuery);

/* ========================================================================
 * Bootstrap: transition.js v3.4.0
 * https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#transitions
 * ========================================================================
 * Copyright 2011-2018 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 * ======================================================================== */


+function ($) {
  'use strict';

  // CSS TRANSITION SUPPORT (Shoutout: https://modernizr.com/)
  // ============================================================

  function transitionEnd() {
    var el = document.createElement('bootstrap')

    var transEndEventNames = {
      WebkitTransition : 'webkitTransitionEnd',
      MozTransition    : 'transitionend',
      OTransition      : 'oTransitionEnd otransitionend',
      transition       : 'transitionend'
    }

    for (var name in transEndEventNames) {
      if (el.style[name] !== undefined) {
        return { end: transEndEventNames[name] }
      }
    }

    return false // explicit for ie8 (  ._.)
  }

  // https://blog.alexmaccaw.com/css-transitions
  $.fn.emulateTransitionEnd = function (duration) {
    var called = false
    var $el = this
    $(this).one('bsTransitionEnd', function () { called = true })
    var callback = function () { if (!called) $($el).trigger($.support.transition.end) }
    setTimeout(callback, duration)
    return this
  }

  $(function () {
    $.support.transition = transitionEnd()

    if (!$.support.transition) return

    $.event.special.bsTransitionEnd = {
      bindType: $.support.transition.end,
      delegateType: $.support.transition.end,
      handle: function (e) {
        if ($(e.target).is(this)) return e.handleObj.handler.apply(this, arguments)
      }
    }
  })

}(jQuery);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PmY9l28YgO4JwMKbTvgaS7XNZJ30MK9FAZjjzXtlqyZCqBY6X6bXIkM++IkyinN+" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
  Link with href
</a>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
  Button with data-target
</button>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  <div class="well">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```